# WPF: Localization using RESX not working in Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization, resx

I am localizing my project using the RESX way (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files).

I have had no problems so far when localizing strings inside the `<Window>` scope, for instance:

```
ribbon:RibbonTab Header="{Resx W.Misc}"
```

I tried to localize strings inside the `<Window.Resource>`, for example:

```
<Button x:Key="Misc Button" Content ="{Resx W.Misc}"></Button>
```

When I used the resource, the button instead shows up: `#W.Misc`.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grant Frisken actually helped me to solve this problem:

"The DefaultResxName specified for the window does not work for Window.Resource because the resource is not a framework element parented by the window. So you will have to explicitly set the ResxName property. For instance:"

```
<Button x:Key="Misc Button" Content ="{Resx ResxName=WpfApp.MainWindow, Key=W.Misc}"></Button>
```